# How to remove the object if the nested object meets the condition in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I a have collection which is contain places related data. For a place there can be multiple bookings. booking details saved in a another collection. these two collections as follow.

```
//place collection
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0e01f3cd2767d8b9d1d884"),
    "name" : "abc"
}
//booking collection
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0e0260cd2767d8b9d1da32"),
    "placeId" : ObjectId("5f0e01f3cd2767d8b9d1d884"),
    "startDate" : ISODate("2020-07-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "endDate" : ISODate("2020-07-27T00:00:00.000Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0e02e6cd2767d8b9d1dc38"),
    "placeId" : ObjectId("5f0e01f3cd2767d8b9d1d884"),
    "startDate" : ISODate("2020-07-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "endDate" : ISODate("2020-07-30T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

so i need to find availability of a place for a specific date. So i tried with following query.

```
var date = ISODate("2020-07-25T00:00:00.000Z");
db.getCollection('place').aggregate([
{"$lookup":{"from":"booking","localField":"_id","foreignField":"placeId","as":"bookings"}},
{
   "$match":{
      "$or":[
         {"bookings.startDate":{"$gt":date}},
         {
            "$and":[
               {"bookings.startDate":{"$lte":date}},
               {"bookings.endDate":{"$lt":date}}
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
]);
```

Result is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0e01f3cd2767d8b9d1d884"),
    "name" : "abc",
    "bookings" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0e0260cd2767d8b9d1da32"),
            "placeId" : ObjectId("5f0e01f3cd2767d8b9d1d884"),
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-07-25T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-07-27T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0e02e6cd2767d8b9d1dc38"),
            "placeId" : ObjectId("5f0e01f3cd2767d8b9d1d884"),
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-07-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-07-30T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

basically if this specific place not available for a date, then result should not come. But here, for this place it has multiple booking, only one booking is met the match criteria. so i need to remove whole result if one the booking data is met the criteria. How can i do that ?

i tried the query with `$not` condition.

```
var date = ISODate("2020-07-28T00:00:00.000Z");
db.getCollection('place').aggregate([
{"$lookup":{"from":"booking","localField":"_id","foreignField":"placeId","as":"bookings"}},
{
   "$match":{
      "$or":[
         {"bookings.startDate":{"$not":{"$gt":date}}},
         { 
            "$and":[
               {"bookings.startDate":{"$not":{"$lte":date}}},
               {"bookings.endDate":{"$not":{"$lt":date}}}
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
]);
```

This is works with the date of 25th,26th,27th. but for 28,place should be available but it is not coming with the result.

Comment: Use $not. Just like a query is satisfied when one of the array elements meets its respective requirements,  $not would require that no elements meet the requirements.

Comment: if i applied $ result if same because one inner object meet the requirement other one is not.

Comment: Add the not working $not version to the question.

Comment: @D.SM i have updated the question.

Comment: Needs to be an expression level $not, yes? Since it is not directly supported by MQL you can emulate that with $nor.

Comment: @D.SM i have posted an answer. Thanks for your support. I tried with lookup pipeline. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved this problem with lookup pipeline as follow.

```
var date = ISODate('2020-07-28T00:00:00.000Z');
db.getCollection('place').aggregate([
{'$lookup':{
    'from':'booking',
    'let':{'place':'$_id','checkingDate':date},
    'pipeline': [{ '$match':{ 
                    '$expr':{
                        '$and':[
                            {'$eq':['$placeId','$$place']},
                            {'$not':{'$gt':['$startDate','$$checkingDate']}},
                            {'$not':{'$lt':['$endDate','$$checkingDate']}}
                         ]}}}
    ],
    'as':'bookings'
    }
}
,
{'$match':{'bookings':{ '$exists': 'true','$size': 0}}}
]);
```